# Firefox inside of a Docker-Container is very slow - How to get Drivers inside

Tags: linux, docker, opengl, webgl

I am trying to put a Firefox Webbrowser into a Docker-Container and access it via X2Go.
It works, but it is unusable slow.
Looking at about:support it seems it misses drivers.

What drivers are needed to make the experience usable and how can i get them into a Docker-Container?

[image: The Output of the about:support-Site]

Comment: You're accessing a complicated multimedia program like a modern browser through a remote desktop protocol. This is often no nice experience. If you're trying to use docker for local security, try running it inside the container but accessing the host computers X11 (unix)sockets or try other sandboxes like firejail.

Comment: @allo correct, most of your issue is probably accessing it over the network, not Docker.

Comment: I tried once x2go outside containers and was not impressed either.

Comment: If you're looking for a fast remote desktop protocol, have a look at Xpra. It uses video codecs for streaming and can be much faster in many cases.